# Angular Full-Stack Generator bootstrap vars overwrite

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, angular-fullstack

I'm new with yeoman Angular Full-Stack Generator and I'm looking for the best way(or at least a way) to overwrite vars from bootstrap using sass. I couldn't find any info on the docs.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is from the begining of my app.scss file:**

```css
//** Library variable overides
$gray-lighter: rgba(245,245,245,1);
$gray-light: darken($gray-lighter, 20%);
$gray: darken($gray-light, 20%);
$text-muted: $gray;
$font-family-sans-serif: Ubuntu;
$border-radius-base: 3px;
$border-radius-large: 4px;
$border-radius-small: 2px;
$font-size-base: 12px;
$icon-font-path: '/assets/fonts/bootstrap/';
$fa-font-path: '/assets/fonts/font-awesome/';
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//** Library imports
@import 'animate/animate.css';
@import '~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap';
@import '~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu');
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```